# Is there a possibility that I'll make the Stripe payment in my app less secured due to wrong implementation?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe in my app, and currently having a bit of a hard time. Like anything else I believe that eventually I'd be able to make it work, but my main concern is that I won't implement it properly, and as a result I'll make the payment less secure that it should be.

Is there a base to my concerns? The last thing I want is to compromise my users credit cards.

I am trying to use the standard implementation and collect the card details with their card input widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think security should be a concern, that's what stripe is for. Improper implementation won't make it less secure. You just won't get the right response.

FYI - https://stripe.com/docs/security/stripe
https://stripe.com/docs/security

As long as you follow the official documentation, you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying but having a hard time. I feel likeaybr there is some knowledge I'm missing? Other than kotlin/Java, android development and working with JSON, is there something else I need to know to implement it properly?

Comment: Have you worked with retrofit, if so that's pretty much it.

Comment: I haven't, never heard that term before actually (only been coding for 4 months now). I'll search it, thanks!

Comment: it's an HTTP client for API calls. FYI - https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Stripe's preferred integrations such as [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout), raw card details are always handled within an iframe controlled by Stripe. As such they will never touch your server or be accessible to your code.

That said, there are other potential vulnerabilities in a web application to consider and mitigate (XSS, SQL injection, sanitation of user inputs, server mis-configs or outdated packages) but these aren't specific to collecting card details through Stripe.